# Python: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arrTime' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, исключения, numpy, ос

Подскажите решение проблемы:
программа выдаёт исключение `UnboundLocalError` в следующем цикле:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    firstFile = True
    for name in files:
        if firstFile:                
            currentTaskValues = os.path.splitext(name)[0].replace('p', '.').replace('m', '-').replace('s', '').split('_')
            currentTaskValues = removeAlphabeticSymbols(currentTaskValues)
            firstFile = False

        currentFileContent = os.path.splitext(name)[0].split('_')[-1]

        if currentFileContent == 'accelerations':   
            arrTime, arrAccLat, arrAccLon, arrAccRol, arrAccYaw = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(root, name), skiprows=7, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), unpack=True)       
        elif currentFileContent == 'displacements':
            arrDspSum, arrDspLat, arrDspLon, arrDspRol, arrDspYaw = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(root, name), skiprows=7, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), unpack=True)
        elif currentFileContent == 'forces':
            arrLeFro, arrLeRea, arrRiFro, arrRiRea = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(root, name), skiprows=7, usecols=(1,2,3,4), unpack=True)
        elif currentFileContent == 'steering':
            arrSWAng, arrSWRotSpd, arrToeLeFro, arrToeLeRea = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(root, name), skiprows=7, usecols=(1,2,3,4), unpack=True)
        elif currentFileContent == 'velocities':
            arrVelLat, arrVelLon, arrVelRol, arrVelYaw = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(root, name), skiprows=7, usecols=(1,2,3,4), unpack=True)
        elif currentFileContent == 'wheelslipangles':
            arrSideSlAng, arrLeSlFro, arrLeSlRea, arrRiSlFro, arrRiSlRea = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(root, name), skiprows=7, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), unpack=True)
        else:
            raise SystemExit('Unable to open file {:s}'.format(currentFileContent))

    indStartTime = np.argwhere(np.abs(arrTime - 4.0) < 1e-4)[0,0]
```

Ругается на последнюю приведенную строку.

Суть в следующем: в каждой директории, содержащей *файлы*, их количество **всегда равно 6**, и всегда должны присутствовать именно указанные файлы (имена которых заканчиваются на приведенные в блоке `if` строки). Казалось бы, внутри вложенного цикла `for name in files:` должны прочитаться все 6 файлов, и далее, после него, но *находясь в данной папке*, т.е. не переходя на следующую итерацию внешнего цикла, должны быть доступны *все* считанные массивы данных. Если последнюю строку внести во внутренний цикл, то исключения нет, но она естественно выполняется 6 раз, а надо **ровно один**.

Comment: Ну как минимум arrTime у вас может быть неиницилизирована, поскольку инициализация зависит от выполнения условия

Comment: Так собственно я и не понимаю -- почему? ведь **все** фалы присутствуют, значит после прохождения цикла во все условия `if` был произведён заход. Разве нет?

Comment: Отладчик берите и смотрите, что выполняется, что нет. Или print на крайний случай. О ваших файлах мне ничего не известно.

Comment: @Дмитрий, добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки. Там в частности должна быть указана переменная, с которой возникла проблема, у вас в вопросе это не указано. Плюс, похоже у вас код в функции (раз пишет, что проблема с локальной переменной), возможно вы пытаетесь обратиться на запись к глобальной переменной, не указав функции `global имя_переменной`.

Comment: @insolor, действительно, приведенный код выполняется внутри функции, но переменная `arrTime` кроме этой функции, более того - кроме внешнего цикла, нигде не фигурирует.

Comment: Ну значит два варианта: либо папка пустая, либо в ней нет файлов с `accelerations` в имени. И тот и другой случай желательно обрабатывать.